# "$npm_execpath" isn't recognized as an internal or external command, program, or executable batch file

Tags: reactjs, npm, yarnpkg, package.json, npm-scripts

The title is the error that's occurring. I create scripts in my package.json but I want to use `npm` or `yarn` dynamically. I've read it's possible use an environment variable called "$npm_execpath" for this but it doesn't work with my configuration. This is an example of the package.json part:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "run-p start:jsonserver start:dev",
    "start:dev": "node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --config ./config/webpack/webpack.standalone.dev.js --open",
    "start:prod": "webpack-dev-server --config ./config/webpack/webpack.standalone.prod.js",
    "start:container": "webpack-dev-server --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4555",
    "start:jsonserver": "node ../Testing.GtP.UI.MockServer/server.js",
    "build:dev": "npm run build:standalone:dev && npm run build:module:dev"
  },
```

I'm trying to run the "build" script as follows:

`yarn build / npm run build`

But in each ones show the error:

> "$npm_execpath" isn't recognized as an internal or external command, program, or executable batch file

I hope you can help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Referencing environment variables:

Environment variables are referenced using a different syntax per operating system:

- On [**nix*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix-like) operating systems, such as macOS and Linux, they are referenced using a dollar sign prefix. For instance:

  ```
  $npm_execpath
  ^
  ```
- On Windows they are referenced using a percent sign on both sides. For instance:

  ```
  %npm_execpath%
  ^            ^
  ```

---

#### Check the environment variable exists

Firstly, check whether the `npm_execpath` variable exists by temporarily adding a new script to the `scripts` section of your *package.json*. Let's name the script `test-var` and define it as follows depending on which OS you're running:

1. **For Windows (cmd)**

   If you are running Windows define the script as follows:

   ```json
   "scripts": {
     "test-var": "echo %npm_execpath%",
     ...
   }
   ```
2. **For macOS/Linux (bash)**

   If you are running macOS/Linux (i.e. bash) then define the script as follows:

   ```json
   "scripts": {
     "test-var": "echo $npm_execpath",
     ...
   }
   ```

Then invoke the script by running the following command(s): `npm run test-var` and `yarn test-var`.

If the `npm_execpath` variable exists you should see a path printed to your console. For instance, on macOS running `npm run test-var` will print something like the following:

> `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js`

On windows, it will print something similar to the following:

> `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js`

It should also print a path when running `yarn test-var`. However, the file the path points to will be a reference to `yarn.js`. For example, on macOS it will print something like this:

> `/Users/someone/.yarn/bin/yarn.js`

**Note:** If no path is printed to your console when running the commands mentioned above then consider re-installing yarn and/or npm.

---

#### Solutions:

1. **For macOS/Linux *(bash)***

   Utilize the `$npm_execpath` variable as you're currently doing.
2. **For Windows *(cmd)***

   Replace *all* instances of `$npm_execpath` in *all* scripts with:

   ```
   node \"%npm_execpath%\"
   ```

   As an example, your current script named `typecheck:watch` will be redefined as:

   ```json
   "scripts": {
     "typecheck:watch": "node \"%npm_execpath%\" run typecheck -- --watch",
     ...
   }
   ```

   In the example above we explicitly utilize *nodejs* to invoke the `npm_execpath` variable. We also place the `npm_execpath` variable between percent signs (i.e. `%...%`), and wrap them also in JSON escaped double quotes (i.e. `\"...\"`).
3. **Cross Platform**

   Having to utilize a different syntax per OS to reference variables is not ideal, especially if your want to support both Windows and *nix operating systems.

   For a single syntax which works cross platform (*Windows*, *macOS*, *Linux*) I suggest installing and utilizing [yarpm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yarpm). In which case replace *all* instances of `$npm_execpath` in *all* scripts with `yarpm`.

   As an example, your current script named `typecheck:watch` will be redefined as:

   ```json
   "scripts": {
     "typecheck:watch": "yarpm run typecheck -- --watch",
     ...
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you so much @RobC ! That's great! I hadn't realized but I had utilized Linux environment variable in Windows :S hahaha

Answer (score 0):

I tried the follow aboves suggestions and didn't work. But, in [this topic](https://github.com/wundergraph/wunderctl/issues/2) I tried add `yarn` in every line that has `$npm_execpath` and did work for me.